# How to perform an outer left join on multiple columns using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, left-join

I have two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2` which I want to perform an outer left join on. However, `df_1` has multiple columns (over 70), all named in the same fashion (e.g. `Team_URL_1`, `Team_URL_2`, and so on) that contain the URLs I want to join with one column from `df_2`.

How do I perform an outer left join for these columns using a loop so that I don't have to code all `URL_` columns manually?

The input dfs look like this (with over 70 Team_URL_ columns in the real dataframe):

```
df_1 <- data.frame (Team_1  = c("wrg", "werg", "sdf"),
                    Team_Desc_1  = c("wer", "wtrb", "wergt"),
                    Team_URL_1 = c("ewrg", "werg", "asd"),
                    Team_Ver_1  = c("25", "2523", "342"),
                    Team_Num_1 = c("aed", "jfsa", "vsf"),
                    Team_Value_1 = c("aed", "jfsa", "vsf"),
                    Team_2  = c("werh", "wtt", "qwe"),
                    Team_Desc_2  = c("sdfg", "wer", "sdfgv"),
                    Team_URL_2 = c("qwe", "gvre", "vrw"),
                    Team_Ver_2  = c("4123", "5133", "4126"),
                    Team_Num_2 = c("aefbvd", "jfswreta", "vsefwf"),
                    Team_Value_2 = c("aewed", "jfsbwa", "vsbf")
)

df_2 <- data.frame (Name  = c("etwbv", "werg", "sdfg", "qwreg", "gvr", "wref"),
                    URL = c("ewrg", "werg", "asd", "qwe", "gvre", "vrw"),
                    Txt = c("abc", "bfh", "fse", "rege", "wer", "vwr"),
                    Head = c("abc1", "bfh", "fse", "rege1", "wer", "vwr")
)
```

The output should look like this (order the Columns containing the respective number in the right order and rename them adding "_x" with x being the respective value):

```
  Column_name_1  Column_URL_1  Name_1  Txt_1  Column_name_2  Column_URL_2  Name_2  Txt_2
1       value_1         URL_1   val_1    abc        value_4         URL_4   val_4   rege
2       value_2         URL_2   val_2    bfh        value_5         URL_5   val_5    wer
3       value_3         URL_3   val_3    fse        value_6         URL_6   val_6    vwr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot to long, then join, then pivot back:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "id"), names_pattern = "(Column_URL|Column_name)_(\\d)") %>% 
  left_join(df_2, by = c("Column_URL" = "URL")) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Column_name:Txt, names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  select(-row_id)

  Column_name_1 Column_URL_1 Name_1 Txt_1 Column_name_2 Column_URL_2 Name_2 Txt_2
1 value_1       URL_1        val_1  abc   value_4       URL_4        val_4  rege 
2 value_2       URL_2        val_2  bfh   value_5       URL_5        val_5  wer  
3 value_3       URL_3        val_3  fse   value_6       URL_6        val_6  vwr
```

---

Edit:

```r
df_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "id"), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\d)$') %>% 
  left_join(df_2, by = c("Team_URL" = "URL")) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Team:Head, names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  select(-row_id)

  Team_1 Team_Des…¹ Team_…² Team_…³ Team_…⁴ Team_…⁵ Name_1 Txt_1 Head_1 Team_2 Team_…⁶ Team_…⁷ 
1 wrg    wer        ewrg    25      aed     aed     etwbv  abc   abc1   werh   sdfg    qwe    
2 werg   wtrb       werg    2523    jfsa    jfsa    werg   bfh   bfh    wtt    wer     gvre   
3 sdf    wergt      asd     342     vsf     vsf     sdfg   fse   fse    qwe    sdfgv   vrw
```

Comment: Thanks @Mael, I edited my input data slightly to resemble my input data more closely - I trid adjusting your code but could not quite figure it out, could you help me with the adjustment?

Comment: Check edit. You have to change the pattern in `names_pattern`

Comment: Thank you! However, now I have 6 rows instead of the origianl 3 from df_1. I still want the Team_2 variables to be in the same first row as the Team_1, so in total only have 3 rows but with the appended new columns from df_2. See my example output.

Comment: No, there are 3 rows with both solutions

Comment: I run the input code as I provided above together with your Edit code and for nrow() I get 6.

Comment: Check your `dplyr` version. If you have `1.0.10` or lower,  update

Comment: That was it - thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: one further question: How do I edit the code if df_1 has an additional column called "Company"? As this is not in the "Team_" pattern, is there a way to keep this original column somehow?

Comment: I see that you created another question. that's good practice, so I'll answer there rather than here