# Addition: How to perform an outer left join on multiple columns using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, left-join, tidyr

I have a further question to this thread: [How to perform an outer left join on multiple columns using a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458092/how-to-perform-an-outer-left-join-on-multiple-columns-using-a-loop)

How can I edit the code to account for multiple (>20) columns in `df_1` as shown below (with the example of two additional columns `Company` and `City`)?

```
df_1 <- data.frame (Company = c("Comp1", "Comp2", "Comp3"),
                    City = c("Atlanta", "New York", "Boston"),
                    Team_1  = c("wrg", "werg", "sdf"),
                    Team_Desc_1  = c("wer", "wtrb", "wergt"),
                    Team_URL_1 = c("ewrg", "werg", "asd"),
                    Team_Ver_1  = c("25", "2523", "342"),
                    Team_Num_1 = c("aed", "jfsa", "vsf"),
                    Team_Value_1 = c("aed", "jfsa", "vsf"),
                    Team_2  = c("werh", "wtt", "qwe"),
                    Team_Desc_2  = c("sdfg", "wer", "sdfgv"),
                    Team_URL_2 = c("qwe", "gvre", "vrw"),
                    Team_Ver_2  = c("4123", "5133", "4126"),
                    Team_Num_2 = c("aefbvd", "jfswreta", "vsefwf"),
                    Team_Value_2 = c("aewed", "jfsbwa", "vsbf")
)

df_2 <- data.frame (Name  = c("etwbv", "werg", "sdfg", "qwreg", "gvr", "wref"),
                    URL = c("ewrg", "werg", "asd", "qwe", "gvre", "vrw"),
                    Txt = c("abc", "bfh", "fse", "rege", "wer", "vwr"),
                    Head = c("abc1", "bfh", "fse", "rege1", "wer", "vwr")
)
```

The code for the original code was provided by @Maël and looks like this:

```
df_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "id"), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\d)$') %>% 
  left_join(df_2, by = c("Team_URL" = "URL")) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Team:Head, names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  select(-row_id)
```

How can I account for the additional columns that do not follow the `Team_` pattern in the other columns and not loose them in the output?

The output should look like this:

```
Company City Team_1 Team_Des…¹ Team_…² Team_…³ Team_…⁴ Team_…⁵ Name_1 Txt_1 Head_1 Team_2 Team_…⁶ Team_…⁷ 
Comp1   Atlanta     wrg    wer        ewrg    25      aed     aed     etwbv  abc   abc1   werh   sdfg    qwe    
Comp2   New York    werg   wtrb       werg    2523    jfsa    jfsa    werg   bfh   bfh    wtt    wer     gvre   
Comp3   Boston      sdf    wergt      asd     342     vsf     vsf     sdfg   fse   fse    qwe    sdfgv   vrw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains` or any other [`tidy-select` functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) in `pivot_longer` to select the columns you which to pivot:

```r
df_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("Team"), names_to = c(".value", "id"), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\d)$') %>% 
  left_join(df_2, by = c("Team_URL" = "URL")) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Team:Head, names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  select(-row_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with the sample data I provided, however, not with the real data. Any idea why that is? I will provide the dput in an edit as soon as Stackoverflow will let me (too many edits atm)

Comment: dput df_1: ```structure(list(Company.x = "0VIX", Team_1 = "Garry Krugljakows", 
    Team_Desc_1 = "CEO", Team_URL_1 = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/garryks/", 
    Team_Ver_1 = "unverified", Team_Num_ICOs_1 = NA_real_, Team_2 = "Hossam", 
    Team_Desc_2 = "CTO", Team_URL_2 = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/hossam/", 
    Team_Ver_2 = "unverified", Team_Num_ICOs_2 = NA_real_), row.names = 5L, class = "data.frame")```

Comment: dput df_2: ```structure(list(name = "Garry Krugljakows", id_LI = "garryk", url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/garryks", 
    city = "Swiss"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```

Comment: I edited the code accordingly (```url``` instead of column ```URL``` in big letters, ```values_from = Team:city``` instead of ```Team:Head```)

Comment: What does not work with your data?

Comment: The strings are different: there is a missing \ at the end

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you. Is there any chance to join them only based until the last  \ , so basically avoiding all the cases where I have URLs that contain an  \  at the end?

Comment: Probably, although that's another question. Joins are based on exact match so it'd be probably better to change your string accordingly

Comment: Ok great, I will add another question for this. Thanks for your help!